# Visualizing XLA graphs before and after optimizations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am playing around with XLA and would like to visually understand the kinds of optimizations XLA performs, specifically kernel fusion. I have been dumping the graphs using the following flags and importing them in tensorboard, but these seem to be the graphs before optimizations. I confirmed that XLA is fusing kernels from the HLA IR that is also dumped.

Environment variables and their values I am using

`TF_DUMP_GRAPH_PREFIX=hlo   TF_XLA_FLAGS="--tf_xla_clustering_debug --tf_xla_auto_jit=2"   XLA_FLAGS="--xla_dump_hlo_as_text --xla_dump_to=./hlo`

Comment: There are hanging ends within XLA optimization for node visualization, but I am not aware of the tool that would be able to visualize them. Yet, here is the best single source video that I know of to explain what XLA does and why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3cWOd99xX0

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code snippet to the optimization passes you want to inspect. `DumpHloModuleIfEnabled` will emit the HLO graph to `./hlo`, for any hlo module.

```cpp
DumpHloModuleIfEnabled(*module, "your_hlo_module_to_print");

// use case:
StatusOr<bool> CustomGraphRewriter::Run(HloModule* module) {
  // this will dump the graph before the optimization
  DumpHloModuleIfEnabled(*module, "before_graph_rewriting");
  bool is_rewriting_done = false;
  TF_ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(is_rewriting_done,
                    RunGraphRewriting(module));
  // this will dump the graph after the optimization
  DumpHloModuleIfEnabled(*module, "after_graph_rewriting");
  return is_rewriting_done;
}
```

For visualizing tool, using **graphviz** would help. After installing **graphviz**, you should emit the graph to *.dot file, with the following flag.

```
XLA_FLAGS="--xla_dump_hlo_as_dot"
```

For visualizing the dot file, this would work:

```sh
dot -Tsvg your_hlo_graph.dot > visualized_output.svg
```

There, this will emit the result as shown in the picture.
[sample HLO graph visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyM4H.png)